# ArcPy Dissolve Statistics Fields

Tags: python, arcpy

While running a [Dissolve](http://resources.arcgis.com/EN/HELP/MAIN/10.2/index.html#//00170000005n000000), when using statistics fields, I keep getting an error that the parameters are not valid.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
toBeDissolved = r"D:\TestingAfterMeeting\toBeDeletedTestingData\output.shp"
output = r'D:\TestingAfterMeeting\toBeDeletedTestingData\TestingDissolve\output_diss.shp'

arcpy.Dissolve_management(toBeDissolved,output,dissolve_field='Code_CLDC',statistics_fields=[['Code_DDA','LAST'],['Code_Provi','LAST'],['Number_CLD ','LAST']])
```

Been looking at it for a while... maybe someone else sees the mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great... the second it is posted I spot the mistake.

There was an extra white space in one of my fields (Number_CLD). I wish the error messages in ArcPy were sometimes more helpful.

Here is the working code:

```
toBeDissolved = r"D:\TestingAfterMeeting\toBeDeletedTestingData\output.shp"
output = r'D:\TestingAfterMeeting\toBeDeletedTestingData\TestingDissolve\output_diss.shp'

arcpy.Dissolve_management(toBeDissolved,output,dissolve_field='Code_CLDC',statistics_fields=[['Code_DDA','LAST'],['Code_Provi','LAST'],['Number_CLD','LAST']])
```